# Composing several Rx actions without side effects

Tags: c#, system.reactive

How do I add (compose) more actions, e.g, updateIndicators, instead of the single action so that information flows without side effects?

```
quote => 
{ 
    this.changeQuote(quote.S, quote.B, quote.A);
} // Add action here, e.g., UpdateIndicators()



var qu = Observable.FromEvent<ApiQuoteHandler, QuoteUpdate>(
                    emit => (_, s, b, a) => emit(new QuoteUpdate(s, b, a)),
                    handler => apiClient.QuoteUpdated += handler,
                    handler => apiClient.QuoteUpdated -= handler)
                                .Where(quote => (SymbolStrs.Contains(quote.S)))
                                .SubscribeOn(Scheduler.Default)
                                .Subscribe
                            (
                                quote => 
                                { 
                                    this.changeQuote(quote.S, quote.B, quote.A);
                                    // I could put updateIndicators in here, but it doesn't feel Rx composable like?
                                }
                            );

public void changeQuote(string symbol, double bid, double ask)
{
}

public void updateIndicators(string symbol, double bid, double ask)
{
}

// more actions here
```

Comment: Can you explain what "information flows without side effects" means to you?

Comment: And what's wrong with doing multiple calls to `void` methods in a subscription. That's where they belong.

Answer (score 0):

Well first obviously both of your actions will be nothing but **sideeffects**.

So the just either call subscribe 2 times:

```
var quoteUpdate = 
    Observable.FromEvent<ApiQuoteHandler, QuoteUpdate>(
        emit => (_, s, b, a) => emit(new QuoteUpdate(s, b, a)),
        handler => apiClient.QuoteUpdated += handler,
        handler => apiClient.QuoteUpdated -= handler)
    .Where(quote => (SymbolStrs.Contains(quote.S)));

var subscription1 =
    quoteUpdate
    .SubscribeOn(Scheduler.Default)
    .Subscribe (quote => this.changeQuote(quote.S, quote.B, quote.A));

var subscription2 =
    quoteUpdate
    .SubscribeOn(Scheduler.Default)
    .Subscribe (quote => this.updateIndicators(quote.S, quote.B, quote.A));
```

or subscribe to one Action that will just call one after the other (as you already guessed - don't see what's wrong with it):

```
public void DoBoth(string symbol, double bid, double ask)
{
    changeQuote(symbol,bid,ask);
    updateIndicators(symbol,bid,ask);
}

// ...
var subscription =
    quoteUpdate
    .SubscribeOn(Scheduler.Default)
    .Subscribe (quote => this.DoBoth(quote.S, quote.B, quote.A));
```

### remark:

right now you are only using `Where` and `SubscribeOn` from RX but you have quite a few lines of overhead. If you don't want to do more I would suggest just handling the event itself with a simple `if` instead of the `.Where` (of course dispatching to the UI Thread if you really have to) - it's way easier and you don't need the external dependency to RX then

Comment: Thanks. So are you saying the overhead is strictly code that the compiler optimizes away, or it is actually dead  code that adds no value other than adding CPU cycles. I am just taking first steps with Rx and trying to get at its value, which to me is fluency through composition, and a CEP like environment (Linq) that makes it far more expressive and compact than imperative styles for this sort of event driven domain.

Comment: I meant that you probably should not add dependencies if you don't get to much value from it - not because of optimization/cycles/whatever but because of you having to maintain that codebase